# Errors were encountered while processing fuse

Tags: linux, debian, apt-get

I was updating my system (Debian Sid x64) using `apt-get`, but I got the following error:

```
Setting up fuse (2.9.3-14) ...
dpkg: error processing package fuse (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 fuse
```

I had an error like this before (also with `fuse`), but then there was some information about the error displayed so I could do some research. There's nothing in `/var/log/syslog` or `/var/log/apt/term.log`.

Last time it was solved by updating the kernel, but I would prefer not to update the kernel at the moment without any prove that updating the kernel solves the problem.

Is there any way I can actually see what's causing the error instead of a message that just says it failed to install?

Comment: What happens if you try `apt-get install --only-upgrade fuse`?  Do you get the same message?

Comment: I get `fuse is already the newest version.`, then `1 not fully installed or removed.` and then I get the same messsage again.

Comment: I'm getting this too (Only slightly less annoying than not being able to upgrade my Xserver cause of the nvidia drivers...) the error is being triggered by this line in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst`: `udevadm test -e -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fuse) > /dev/null 2>&1` I have no idea what this is supposed to do but it's exiting with 1 and that's causing the issue...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that line 20 in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst` has a syntax error. According to [this](https://www.mail-archive.com/debian-bugs-dist@lists.debian.org/msg1242584.html) the `-e` should be changed to `-a`. I did that and finally installed on my test VM.

So

```
udevadm test -e -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fuse) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Becomes

```
udevadm test -a -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fuse) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution:

```
mkdir /dev/fuse
chmod 777 /dev/fuse

apt-get install fuse
```

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Your [answer](http://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) could benefit from more detail. Please edit it to explain how  your solution works/how it addresses the OPs question.

Comment: I don't see why this answer was downvoted. It solved the problem perfectly. I first checked the `udevadm test -a` line, and it was fine. Simply creating the directory with the right perms fixed the problem and fuse installed without problem.