# Error upgrading fuse

Tags: linux, debian, fuse

As I encouter this error now on three (!) machines and manage to find nothing helpful on the internet, I'll ask a question here. 
As in [this](https://superuser.com/questions/790754/errors-were-encountered-while-processing-fuse/790800#790800) question, I get the error message

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
fuse
```

Neither `/var/log/syslog`, nor `/var/log/apt/term.log` have particular useful information in them. As the only answer in the linked question suggest, there is a syntax error in `/var/lib/dpkg/info/fuse.postinst`, however, my `fuse.postinst` seems to differ too much.
The suspected line for me is the following

```
udevadm test --action -p  $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/fuse) > /dev/null 2>&1
```

I use `Debian testing stretch` on all machines. `makedev` is installed. How can I fix this without removing fuse and *all* its dependencies?

EDIT: As my question has been marked as duplicate, I'll explain further why it isn't.
Line 20, where the error seems to be for the duplicate, is for me the following line:

```
            if udevadm control --reload-rules > /dev/null 2>&1
```

In fact, the suspected line referred to in the answer is not contained in my file nor any similar (besides the one I did add in the description here, the `udevadm test`-thing) at any line.

Comment: Related http://superuser.com/a/790800/550853

Comment: @GAD3R Thank you, I actually forgot to include it

Comment: @JeffBridgman Did you even read my question? It is not a duplicate, as I state, my `fuse.postinst` looks totally different.

Comment: Ah, I misunderstood your comment. I thought you were saying you found something you were missing in the other question (therefore, it answered your question).